# How to join 2 tables with no common column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

eg

Names

```
id  | name
1      abc
2      efg
```

Area

```
id  | areaName
3     area1
4     area2
```

The query should return

```
 id  | name | areaid
 1     abc    3
 1     abc    4
 2     efg    3
 2     efg    4
```

Comment: How can this question about a simple cross join not have been asked before!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the ecpected result:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.id from names,area
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to join all records from table A to all records from table B (i.e. get a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), you can use [`CROSS JOIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html):

```
SELECT Names.id, Names.name, Area.areaid
FROM Names
CROSS JOIN Area
ORDER BY Names.id, Area.areaid
```